# Why are modules explicitly named in files?

Tags: compiler-construction, d, language-design

From the [D language reference](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/module.html):

> Modules have a one-to-one correspondence with source files. The module name is the file name with the path and extension stripped off.

Module names are still specified in files explicitly, though.

```
module foo;
```

What's the point of this?  If modules correspond to files, why can't the compiler infer what they're called from the file names?

Comment: IIUC, D's official site now is [d-programming-language.org](http://d-programming-language.org/module.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

same page a bit down (emph mine)

> The ModuleDeclaration sets the name of the module and what package it
>   belongs to. If absent, the module name is taken to be the same name
>   **(stripped of path and extension)** of the source file name.

this means that if you want to put a module in a package you have to explicitly specify it is (like Java's `package` declaration) and given the strange propensity of people to use odd/foreign directory names you can't rely on checking for source/src/import in the path

the reason that filename and module name don't have to be the same can be so you can use a .di for import and use several versions of the actual code using -c switch to create the .obj file for linking of the different versions (though fiddling with the import path is handier for that)

Comment: Folders do correspond to packages, the path stripping is just referring to the current working directory. The reason to specify the module name is so that the hierarchy does not need maintained to compile the files if passing all needed files to the compiler (di files were added much later).

Answer (score 4):

It *can* infer it. You don't *have* to give the module name. However, you *can* give the module name, which allows you to give it an entirely different name if you want to. A prime example of this is if the file name isn't a valid module name (e.g. my-module.d). In such a case, you can use the `module` declaration to give it a valid module name (e.g. my_module).

It's common practice to put the module name at the top of the file, and usually the module name is the same as the file name, but making it possible to have the module name not exactly match the file name increases flexibility.

Personally, I would generally consider it a bad idea to name the module anything other than the file name, and I'd argue that if the file isn't a valid module name, then the file name should be changed so that it is one, but apparently it was decided that the extra flexibility of making it possible for them not to match was worth having. So, it's in the language.

Comment: If you name the module something other than the filename, import statements will not be able to find it.

Comment: @FeepingCreature It works as long as you compile all of the files at once. I don't know if it's supposed to work with imports or not (you're right that it currently doesn't). But that would be another reason why naming your modules something other than the filename isn't generally a good idea.

Comment: The compiler don't need to be able to find the .d if it can find a correct .di

Comment: @BCS Assuming that you're using a .di file, which causes its own set of issues. But if you're renaming the module just because you want to put '-' in the file name instead of '\_' (which is the example that TDPL gives), you're going to have exactly the same problem with the .di file, unless you're willing to name _that_ file properly, in which case why not name the original file properly?